# How can i remove customer in quickbooks using consolibyte API?

Tags: php, quickbooks

I am using consolibyte API to add and edit opration for customers. Now i have scenario in which i have to remove customer from quickbooks using consolibyte's API.

I didn't find any reference for this operation in consolibyte's [qbxml example](http://www.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_example_qbxml) page.
Can anyone help me to find out, how can i achieve this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the link on the wiki to the new example page:

- http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/Example_qbXML_Requests

Specifically, these deletes:

- deleting list records - http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/QbXML_for_Deleting_%22List%22_Objects_(Customers,_Vendors,_Items,_etc.)
- deleting transactions - http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/QbXML_for_Deleting_%22Transaction%22_Objects_(Invoices,_Journal_Entries,_etc.)

Comment: Correct, in response i received this error messages "3175: There was an error adding, modifying or deleting the Customer specified by the id = XXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXX (listid) because it is already in use."

Comment: I guess i found why it was giving me error, user's balance causing the issue. If user's balance total is 0.00 then and then only we can remove user from the list. So another question is how can i remove users with balance total > 0.00 in quickbooks.

Comment: You can't. QuickBooks doesn't support this - this mirrors the behavior of the QuickBooks GUI.